# How to query Where Datetime many time?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, date-arithmetic

I want query datetime many time.
but i try query it's not work.

**Example**

Table cus_bill

```
Number       Period
A-20160101   01/2015
A-20160410   04/2015
A-20160912   09/2015
A-20161020   10/2015
A-20161102   11/2015
A-20161219   12/2015
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT v.*
FROM cus_bill v
WHERE TO_DATE('01/'||V.PERIOD,'DD/MM/YYYY') >= TO_DATE('01/'|| '10/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') 
and TO_DATE('01/'||V.PERIOD,'DD/MM/YYYY') <= TO_DATE('01/'|| '12/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')
and V.PERIOD IN ('01/2015','09/2015')
```

But it's not work (0 Rows).

**Desired output:**

```
Number       Period
A-20160101   01/2015
A-20160912   09/2015
A-20161020   10/2015
A-20161102   11/2015
A-20161219   12/2015
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want here. Can you tell us **with a sentence** what are the selection criteria?

Comment: How could a date be between October and December **and** in January?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE TO_DATE('01/'||V.PERIOD,'DD/MM/YYYY') >= TO_DATE('01/'|| '10/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') 
and TO_DATE('01/'||V.PERIOD,'DD/MM/YYYY') <= TO_DATE('01/'|| '12/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')
and V.PERIOD IN ('01/2015','09/2015')
```

You won't get any rows because you are using **AND** condition along with **IN** condition which will never be true as you can never have `'01/2015'` or `'09/2015'` between `01/10/2015` and `01/12/2015`. i.e. a date cannot be between `Oct` and `Dec` and also in `Jan` or `Sep` simultaneously.

You need an **OR** condition. Also, you could use **BETWEEN** condition for less code:

```
WHERE   TO_DATE('01/'|| V.PERIOD,'DD/MM/YYYY') 
BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/'|| '10/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') 
AND     TO_DATE('01/'|| '12/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') 
OR      V.PERIOD IN  ('01/2015','09/2015')
```